# Voting system issus

Tags: php, html

When I click on the first button the variable increases by one but when I click on the second the first variable become 0 How can fix that ? there is any other method to do that ? 
Code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
   <title>some Texte</title>
  </head>

  <body>
   <?php
    session_start();

   if (!isset($_POST['add'])) {
    $_SESSION['num'] = 0; 
  }
if (!isset($_POST['add1'])) {
   $_SESSION['num1'] = 0; 
 }
?>

<form method='post'>
 <input name='add' type="submit" value='Vote!'>
 <h3><em>Number of Votes:<?php echo $_SESSION['num']++ ?> </em></h3>
 <input name='add1' type="submit" value='Vote!'>
 <h3><em>Number of Votes:<?php echo $_SESSION['num1']++ ?> </em></h3> 
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because in your code you said if the first button isn't clicked set `num` to 0...

Comment: So I have to delete the "!" and replace 0  by $_SESSION[num] = $_SESSION[num]++ ??

Comment: It's hard to help without knowing what the expected behavior should be.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I just trying simple Voting system where if you clicked on the first button the var num increase by one and same with the second button

Comment: So I fix that issus but did you know why if I refresh the page the num var increases by 1 also please ??

Comment: If you keep refreshing the page does it keep increasing? It's because the POST request is being resubmitted

Comment: So how to stop this ??